# No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionViewClass'

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

i am getting error in my xml file i have mentioned the min sdk to 11 and i have included v4 support library also its pinching my head please help me

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"        
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    myapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />



<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: android.support.v7 is in v7 support library.

Comment: yes i am added both v7 and v4 support library

Comment: Post the complete xml file including menu tag.

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    
    
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"        
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        myapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    
    

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>

Comment: You can try the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20922323/4186942).`<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
    share:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    share:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="@string/abc_searchview_description_search" />`